# Meaning of "He didn't move that we weren't with him"

Tags: vocabulary

This is from a video I watched. The police are watching a suspect. The first sentence is fine, but I couldn't figure out the bold part. The quote is:

> We set up an overwatch position across the street and **he didn't move
>   that we weren't with him.**

Comment: It means he didn't move that _they weren't aware of his position at every moment_.

Comment: he didn't move SO they weren't aware of his position at every moment?

Comment: No, he didn't make a move that they did not see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an "elided" phrase before (or "replaced by") ***that*** in this (not *desperately* uncommon, but IMHO slightly "slangy/dialectal" and/or dated) usage...

> *He didn't move [in any circumstances] that we weren't with him.*
>   *He didn't move [when] we weren't with him.*

Removing the cumbersome negation from both verbs, and reversing the sequence...

> *We were with him **whenever** he moved*

---

I can't easily track down a free-access website covering this usage, but here's the relevant definition from the full (subscription-only) OED...

> **that** 5.
>    With a negative in the subord. clause (the principal clause having also a negative expressed or implied): = **But that, but** (= Latin **quin**): see **but** conj. 12   (Now expressed by **without** with gerund: e.g. in quot. 1809, ‘without her hearing’.)
>
> Usage instances...
>   1809   R. Southey Let. to Lieut. Southey 19 Sept.
>    *He never turned in his bed during that whole time **that** she did not hear.*
>
> 1837   S. R. Maitland 6 Lett. Fox's A. & M. 69,
>    *I have hardly ever..turned it over for five minutes, **that** some gross error has not presented itself.*